# How to read a substring of JSON and convert to a list of objects

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following json string.

```
{
  {
    "ResponseXML": null,
    "Number": null,
    "RecordType": {
      "Type": "Location"
    },
    "LocationLicense": [
      {
        "CompanyName": "NGM",
        "CompanyCode": "000",
        "STADesc": "Arizona",
        "STACode": "02",
        "PostalAbbr": "AZ",
        "LICNumber": "0"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "MSA Insurance Co of SC",
        "CompanyCode": "004",
        "STADesc": "Arizona",
        "STACode": "02",
        "PostalAbbr": "AZ",
        "LICNumber": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
```

The following code successfully extracts the LocationLicense objects and converts them to a List of LocationLicense objects.

```
    var resStr = await _client.PostAsync(_uri, new StringContent(Req_json_data, Encoding.Default, "application/json"));
    var obj = resStr.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            _log.Debug(callingApp + " returned: " + obj);
    dynamic agentobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(obj);
    string locations = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(agentobj.LocationLicense);
```

The last line shown above returns null.

How can I get the "LocationLicense" section and convert it to a `List<LocationLicense>` ?

Comment: The json you provide is not valid, check it here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ , it says:  Error:  [Code 4, Structure 1]  Error:  [Code 22, Structure 73]

Comment: Jonas Tuemand Møller - this is the json returned from the web service call.

Comment: Is it possible there are one too many left curly brackets at the beginning? Web Services generally don't return invalid json. If i remove the first left curly bracket what remains is valid json, if i use the code you gave as an example it works and i don't get null from the last line

Comment: Your Json not valid,you must remove { at the first json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is not valid. But if you remove one curly brasket in the beginning, you can use this code

```
JArray locationLicenses = (JArray) JObject.Parse(obj)["LocationLicense"];

string companyCode = (string) locationLicenses[1]["CompanyCode"];
```

if you like the very slow code you can use dynamic

```
dynamic LocationLicenses=locationLicenses.ToObject<dynamic>();
string companyCode =  locationLicenses[1].CompanyCode;
```

but IMHO it is better to create a LocationLicense class

```
List<LocationLicense> locationLicenses = JObject.Parse(obj)["LocationLicense"]
                                                .ToObject<List<LocationLicense>>();
```